# Rails show company name rather than company ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am making good progress with my first Rails app with a *lot* of help from the great community here at Stack Overflow.

I have a basic application that has the following models:

kase
person
company
party

I have associated them in the following way:

```
class Kase   
belongs_to :company # foreign key: company_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :people # foreign key in join table

class Person
has_and_belongs_to_many :kases # foreign key in join table

class Company
has_many :kases
has_many :people

class Party
has_and_belongs_to_many :people
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
```

At the moment, if I create a company and then go to create a new case (kase), I can choose from a drop down list the company I want (from the companies database) and then on the show view I can output the name of the chosen company for the case by using this code:

```
<li>Client Company: <span><%=h @kase.company.companyname %></span></li>
```

However, if I add a new Person using the same method - I can successfully assign a company to the person, but on the show view it only outputs the company ID number using this code:

```
<li>Person Company: <span><%=h @person.company.company_id %></span></li>
```

If I change the above to:

```
<li>Person Company: <span><%=h @person.company.companyname %></span></li>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `company' for #<Person:0x105dc4938>
```

So it seems I can call the company ID, but nothing else from the company database, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :kases
end
```

This means that you can do

```
@person = Person.find(1)
@person.kases.each do |kase|
  puts kase.company.name
end
```

But keep in mind that, in order for `@person.company` to work, you would need to have one of the following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company  # option 1
  has_one :company     # option 2
end
```

Comment: +1 wow! Justice you type so long and still beats me by one second ;-)

Comment: The only thing that doesnt work is when I create a new person and choose the company from the drop down I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `companyname' for #<Person:0x105e66cd8>

EDIT: Nevermind - erroneous left in code from earlier today! Thanks All!

Comment: I have now fixed the error message, but if I use the following:

<%=h @kase.person.personname %>

It throws an exception error. Should that happen?

Comment: Since Kase-to-people is a has and belongs to many relationship, doing @kase.person isn't meaningful.

It would be a bit like asking somebody, "hey what is your friend's name?": without knowing which friend you are referring to it would be impossible to answer the question.

Something like this should work: <%=h @kase.people.first.personname %>.

This is finding the first person in the list of people associated with the kase, and getting their name. Note that person has changed to people due to it being a has and belongs to many relationship.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you can even call the company_id like that, are you sure you aren't doing:

```
<li>Person Company: <span><%=h @person.company_id %></span></li>
```

I think the problem is that you are missing the reference to Company in your Person model. Try changing your Person model to:

```
class Person
has_and_belongs_to_many :kases # foreign key in join table
belongs_to :company
```

This should allow you to do lookups between people and companies in both directions.

Comment: I tried that and as above I get an exception error if I do this:

<%=h @kase.person.personname %>

However, the following works:

<%=h @kase.company.companyname %>

Answer (score 1):

not tested, did you try add:

```
belongs_to :company
```

in Person model?